# Cannot resolve method inflate(android.context.Context)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm facing Problems with this method where it says `Cannot resolve method inflate(android.context.Context)`

```
@Override
public exViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType){
    View view= LayoutInflater.inflate(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_thighlayout,parent,false);
    exViewHolder evh=new exViewHolder(view);  return evh;
}
```

Comment: `LayoutInflater.inflate(parent.getContext())` supposed to be a `LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())`.

Comment: Try adding it as answer @Wizard

Comment: okay thanks that was a silly mistake by me it got solved now

Comment: @Wizard Add this as an answer and RUCHIT, accept it if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace,

```
View view= LayoutInflater.inflate(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_thighlayout,parent,false);
```

with

```
View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_thighlayout,parent,false);
```